# How to draw a trend line on the chart?

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

I want to draw a **trend line** on the chart in MQL5.
I tried it with this method:

```
ChartIndicatorAdd(0,0,handle);
```

However, it did not work and getting below error:-

> runtime error (4107)

Comment: Define "it did not work".

Comment: I got a runtime error (4107).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to attach an indicator to the chart or do you want to draw a (trend) line?

If you want to draw a line, use the `ObjectCreate` function to create line objects.

For instance: `ObjectCreate(chart_id,"bullish",OBJ_TREND,sub_window,time1,price1,time2,price2);`

If you want to draw the trend line on the current chart, use 0 for `chart_id`. In addition, `sub_window` refers to the chart sub-window (i.e. 0 for the main chart window).

The `ObjectCreate` method returns false in case of an error, as a result you may want to add a check like this:

```
if(!ObjectCreate(chart_ID,"bullish",OBJ_TREND,sub_window,time1,price1,time2,price2))
     {
        Print(__FUNCTION__,": failed to draw trend line! Error code: ",GetLastError());
     }
```

Make sure to reset the error code with `ResetLastError();`.

Last but not least, object properties like **color** can be set with the `ObjectSetInteger` function.

Read more: [ObjectCreate](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/objects/objectcreate), [ObjectSetInteger](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/objects/objectsetinteger).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I thought that I had to use an indicator, so I used the wrong method. Now it works. Thanks!